# SQL Server : How to sum respectively column value to next column

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have following table...

```
code    date           amount        balamt
   -------------------------------------
1    2015—03—01         10            
1    2015—03—02         15
1    2015—03—03         20
1    2015—03—04         12
2    2015—03—05         15 
2    2015—03—01         10            
2    2015—03—02         20
2    2015—03—03         10
```

I want to get result like this...

```
code    date           amount        balamt
     -------------------------------------
1    2015—03—01         10               10
1    2015—03—02         15               25
1    2015—03—03         20               45
1    2015—03—04         12               57
2    2015—03—05         15               15
2    2015—03—01         10               25
2    2015—03—02         20               45
2    2015—03—03         10               55
```

I also want code group wise data

Comment: What have you already tried? [See this article on how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - I'd also suggest looking at aggregate functions like `SUM` and joining to itsself where the date column is less than itsself

Comment: i want result group wise slcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try something like this (This has not been syntax checked and should be taken as more a pseudo-code guide rather than explicit answer) :

```
SELECT
   t1.DateColumnName
   , t1.AmountColumnName
   , SUM(t2.AmountColumnName)
FROM
   TableName t1
   LEFT JOIN TableName t2 ON t2.DateColumnName <= t1.DateColumnName
GROUP BY
   t1.DateColumnName
   , t1.AmountColumnName
```

Potentially helpful articles:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173454.aspx
- http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/sum.php

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using `CROSS JOIN` and `SUM`. Try something like this,

```
declare @table table(date date, amt decimal(18,2))
insert into @table
values
('2015-03-01', 10),
('2015-03-02', 15),
('2015-03-03', 20),
('2015-03-04', 12),
('2015-03-05', 10)


SELECT t.date, t.amt, SUM(t1.amt) as balamt
FROM @table t 
CROSS JOIN
@table t1
WHERE t1.date <= t.date
GROUP BY t.date, t.amt
ORDER BY balamt
```

[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/78d93/1/0)

For more about calculating sum of previous row value, please refer this article in [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37468/Sum-of-previous-row-values-in-SqlServer).